# Explanation of the law of equivalence

Tags: physical-chemistry, stoichiometry

According to the law of equivalence, the number of equivalents of each reactant and product in a reaction are equal. Why is this the case?

Comment: equivalents are defined that way, btw they aren't really used in practice now

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18693/confusion-with-law-of-equivalence

Comment: Aren't they used for titration ? btw I am preparing for JEE (Engineering entrance exam in India) and its syllabus includes equivalents.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_%28chemistry%29

Comment: Many students are still taught about it but in practice generally moles are used.

Comment: Because of the law of conservation of mass?